# What are the most useful proposed features of C1X?

Tags: c, standards, language-features, c11

What are the most useful proposed features of C1X so far?
And what support for them is there in current compilers?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I have a lot of use for the `_Align( )` specifier and `alignof` operator.  The `_Align` functionality is already pretty well supported in a lot of compilers (`__attribute__((aligned( )))` in GCC, for example), but having a standardized syntax for reasoning about alignment is a welcome addition.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous structs & unions are helpful, and I already use them in GCC (with `-std=gnu99`).

Improved Unicode support is also long-overdue; though I’m not sure if people will switch to the C1x way from current Unicode libs.